# Delete rows when all numbers within a cycle of another variable equal to NA

Tags: r, tidyverse

My data are as follow:

```
Row x   y
1   1   2
2   2   3
3   3   4
4   4   3
5   5   NA
6   1   NA
7   2   NA
8   3   NA
9   4   NA
10  5   7
11  1   NA
12  2   NA
13  3   NA
14  4   NA
15  5   NA
```

I wish to delete Row 11 to 15 since y are NA for ALL cycles of x (y euqal to NA whatever value x takes for Row 11 to 15). I am not going to delete other rows since there is at lease one number of y not NA when x moves from 1 to 5 (Like from Row 6 to 10, y is 7 when x is 5, thus I keep Row 6 to 10). I wish to know how should I write a R code to accompolish this.

Comment: @ Patrick: Do you have only 15 `rows`?  How many rows you have in general? And x is always between 1 to 5?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(cumsum(c(1, diff(x)) < 0)) %>% filter(!all(is.na(y)))` is an option (this will work for any size of cycles)

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan This is a sample data and I have only 15 rows. But answering this question solves  problems with my real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using base R, Taking into assumption that x is arranged and that all start from 1.

```
 subset(df,!ave(is.na(y),cumsum(c(1,diff(x)<0)),FUN=all))
   Row x  y
1    1 1  2
2    2 2  3
3    3 3  4
4    4 4  3
5    5 5 NA
6    6 1 NA
7    7 2 NA
8    8 3 NA
9    9 4 NA
10  10 5  7
```

using tidyverse:

```
df%>%
group_by(m = cumsum(c(1,diff(x)<0)))%>%
filter(!all(is.na(y)))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   m [2]
     Row     x     y     m
   <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     1     1     2     1
 2     2     2     3     1
 3     3     3     4     1
 4     4     4     3     1
 5     5     5    NA     1
 6     6     1    NA     2
 7     7     2    NA     2
 8     8     3    NA     2
 9     9     4    NA     2
10    10     5     7     2
```

of course you can unselect then remove `m`

Comment: Very rigid and clever solution beyond my expectation. Thank you.